# Django create with calculated field

Tags: python, django, isolation-level

Say I have such Django model:

```
class Item(model):
    category = CharField(...)
    weight = IntegerField(...)
```

and I want to create new Item with

`weight=Item.objects.filter(categoty=SOME_CATEGOTY).aggregate(Max('weight'))['weight__max']+1`

The problem is that above query is executed to load data into python, not 
as

`insert into items (category, weight) select SOME_CATEGORY, max(weight)+1 from items where category = SOME_CATEGORY`

So, concurrent creations may create multiple items of same categoty with the same weight, whereas sequential creation always produces distinct weight values. Do I need serializable isolation level to achieve that in two steps: select max then create, or django has built-in mechanism to generate insert with select?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/F3QmONKXcPk